# Replace tags in CMS formated content

Tags: javascript

I'm dealing with a CMS that formats a block of text like so.

> `<p>`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
>   elit.`<br>`Vivamus lacus ipsum, semper non consequat eu, facilisis at
>   lectus. Vestibulum et magna ac`<br>`odio semper porttitor lacinia
>   congue orci. Vivamus suscipit eleifend dolor, in hendrerit`<br>`turpis
>   bibendum ut.`<br><br>`Morbi interdum augue et nisl ullamcorper sit
>   amet ornare`<br>` lorem tempus. Duis nec nisi quis ipsum pulvinar
>   volutpat. Suspendisse venenatis malesuada metus,
> nec pretium dui
>   cursus eget. Donec vitae lorem vitae risus dapibus malesuada congue
>   vel nunc.`</p>`

Double line returns `<br><br>` are used to start new paragraphs. I can't change the CMS output.

Since the block of text already has an opening `<p>` and closing `<p>` around it, I need to first switch double line return tags for an end `</p>` tag and an opening `<p>` tag. Like so: "`<br><br>`" = "`</p><p>`"

and then i need to strip the rest of the remaining 
 tags out and replace with just a space: `<br>` = `" "`

I tried this,

```
$('#nomorefonts').submit(function () {
    $('br').replaceWith(function () {
        return $('</p><p>').append($(this).contents());
    });
    return false;
});
```

But it replaces each `<br>` tags with several opening and closing `</p><p>` tags.

**EDIT:** The desired result is this:

> `<p>`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus
>   lacus ipsum, semper non consequat eu, facilisis at lectus. Vestibulum
>   et magna ac odio semper porttitor lacinia congue orci. Vivamus
>   suscipit eleifend dolor, in hendrerit turpis bibendum ut.`</p><p>`Morbi
>   interdum augue et nisl ullamcorper sit amet ornare  lorem tempus. Duis
>   nec nisi quis ipsum pulvinar volutpat. Suspendisse venenatis malesuada
>   metus, nec pretium dui cursus eget. Donec vitae lorem vitae risus
>   dapibus malesuada congue vel nunc.`</p>`

Comment: Note that what you're proposing doing is semantically ambiguous. You do not know whether two enter key presses were really intended to be a new paragraph or not (unless this is a well-defined markup language like Markdown...but then if it were, you would not have this issue). I would [advise you NOT to change them](http://phrogz.net/css/HowToDevelopWithCSS.html#badBR).

Comment: The company that uses this CMS has made it standard practice to use SHIFT+Enter x 2, to indicate a paragraph break, and a single Shift+Enter as a line break.

Comment: Found the solution to this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144670/javascript-replace-tags-in-cms-formated-content-pt-ii/10145487#10145487

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use `$` to [create a new element](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2), but `</p><p>` isn't an element.

This entire approach seems questionable, but your best bet is to manipulate the raw string:

```
$('.block-of-text').html($('.block-of-text').html().replace(/<br>/g, '</p><p>'));
```

Comment: I recommend using the function form: `.html(function(i,oldVal){ return oldVal.replace(…) })` See http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-functionindex-%20oldhtml

Comment: Yea, good call. That way, you could update all your `.block-of-text`s at once, rather than needing an `each` or a loop.

Comment: This sort of works...
`$('.block-of-text').html($('.block-of-text').html().replace(/<br>/g, '</p><p>'));` 
However, is encapsulating every line if text before each `<br>` tag in it's own paragraph. See my edit above for the desired result.

This was closer to the desired result, but its adding an empty paragraph: `$('#V01-cntntTxt').html($('#V01-cntntTxt').html().replace(/<br><br>/, '</p>'));
   $('#V01-cntntTxt').html($('#V01-cntntTxt').html().replace(/<br>/g, ' '));`

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off with something more like this:

```
$('#target_container p').each(function(){
    var pThis = $(this);
    var pRaw = pThis.html().split('<br>').join('</p><p>');
    pThis.html(pRaw);
});
```

'#target_container' is just where you want to start looking for instances of P elements.  Replace with what works for you.

Better yet, patch the CMS.

Comment: Tried this, and I get "Uncaught ReferenceError $ is not defined". The div container ID is "G02" and I have  `$('#G02 p').each(function(){`

Comment: Although it worked pretty much out of the box, I replaced .html() with replaceWith, which seemed to work better since we were modifying the contents of the object.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XUdYh/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var newHtml = "";
var splitHtml = $("p").html().split("<br>");
for (var i=0; i < splitHtml.length; i++) {
   newHtml += "</p><p>" + splitHtml[i];
}
$("#yourdiv").html(newHtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)? Something like:

```
$('#nomorefonts').submit(function(){
    var elem=$('#text_box'),formattedStr=elem.html().replace(/<br><br>/g,'</p><p>').replace(/<br>/g,' ');
    elem.html(formattedStr);
    return false;
});
```