# Javascript - replace tags in CMS formated content Pt. II

Tags: javascript

I'm dealing with a CMS that formats a block of text like so:

> `<p id="V01-cntntTxt">`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
>   elit.`<br>`Vivamus lacus ipsum, semper non consequat eu, facilisis at
>   lectus. Vestibulum et magna ac`<br>`odio semper porttitor lacinia
>   congue orci. Vivamus suscipit eleifend dolor, in hendrerit`<br>`turpis
>   bibendum ut.`<br><br>`Morbi interdum augue et nisl ullamcorper sit
>   amet ornare`<br>` lorem tempus. Duis nec nisi quis ipsum pulvinar
>   volutpat. Suspendisse venenatis malesuada metus,
> nec pretium dui
>   cursus eget. Donec vitae lorem vitae risus dapibus malesuada congue
>   vel nunc.`</p>`

The company that uses this CMS has made it standard practice to use SHIFT+Enter x 2, to indicate a paragraph break, and a single Shift+Enter as a line break. I am not able to patch or change how the CMS works.

This is the desired result:

> `<p id="V01-cntntTxt">`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus
>   lacus ipsum, semper non consequat eu, facilisis at lectus. Vestibulum
>   et magna ac odio semper porttitor lacinia congue orci. Vivamus
>   suscipit eleifend dolor, in hendrerit turpis bibendum ut.`</p><p>`Morbi
>   interdum augue et nisl ullamcorper sit amet ornare  lorem tempus. Duis
>   nec nisi quis ipsum pulvinar volutpat. Suspendisse venenatis malesuada
>   metus, nec pretium dui cursus eget. Donec vitae lorem vitae risus
>   dapibus malesuada congue vel nunc.`</p>`

I need to replace double `<br><br>` tags with a closing and opening `</p><p>` tag to maintain the paragraph break, and then remove any remaining single `<br>` tags that are for line breaks.

I have tried this, and it almost works:

```
<script>
$('#V01-cntntTxt').html($('#V01-cntntTxt').html().replace(/<br><br>/g, '</p>'));
$('#V01-cntntTxt').html($('#V01-cntntTxt').html().replace(/<br>/g, ' '));
</script>
```

However, the result ends up with an empty paragraph. The two `</p></p>` tags in the middle are backwards. It should be `</p><p>` and not `<p></p>`. It seems as though an opening tag is being inserted even though I have not specified that it should.

This is the result of the above script, with the tags backwards:

> `<p id="V01-cntntTxt">`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
>   adipiscing elit. Vivamus lacus ipsum, semper non consequat eu,
>   facilisis at lectus. Vestibulum et magna ac odio semper porttitor
>   lacinia congue orci. Vivamus suscipit eleifend dolor, in hendrerit
>   turpis bibendum ut.`<p></p>`Morbi interdum augue et nisl ullamcorper
>   sit amet ornare lorem tempus. Duis nec nisi quis ipsum pulvinar
>   volutpat. Suspendisse venenatis malesuada metus, nec pretium dui
>   cursus eget. Donec vitae lorem vitae risus dapibus malesuada congue
>   vel nunc.`</p>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace tags in CMS formated content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132536/replace-tags-in-cms-formated-content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though replacing the `innerHTML` in your `<p>` tag isn't creating a new `<p>` tag as desired, so you should explicitly create one and split the contents into the new `<p>` tag at that point.  For this we'll use `string.split` to split the contents of the string into an array and create a new `<p>` tag for each array index:

```
var par = $('#V01-cntntTxt'); // our first tag
var splits = par.html().split("<br><br>"); // using the first tag to get the array
par.html(splits[0].replace(/<br>/g, " ")); // handling the first index
splits.splice(0, 1) // deleting the first index so it doesnt happen twice
splits.forEach(function(str){ // iterating through the array of strings
    var nPar = $("<p></p>"); // a new <p> tag
    nPar.html(str.replace(/<br>/g, " ")); // removing single <br>s from it
    nPar.insertAfter(par);
    par = nPar; // if another is found it will insert after this
})
```

There is also a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/lq_blocco/KjAjQ/13/) of this.